# debug more then 1 button

Tags: java, android

How would you debug more then 1 button using this method? the first one (imageButton1) shows debug logging but the second one doesn't seem to display any debug msg.

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.imageButton1) {
        Log.d("MEEP", "Image Button1 Pressed");
            if (v.getId() == R.id.imageButton2) {
                Log.d("MEEK", "Image Button2 Pressed");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your second if statement is inside first if statement and both can not be true at the same time.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
   {
  if (v.getId() == R.id.imageButton1) 
    Log.d("MEEP", "Image Button1 Pressed");
  if (v.getId() == R.id.imageButton2) 
    Log.d("MEEK", "Image Button2 Pressed");
   }
```

Comment: Oh.. What a major fault on my part. Thanks!